# Cannot assign string literal to char array

Tags: c++

I have a problem to assign a string literal to an array of `char`s. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct CandyBar{
    char brand[20];
    double weight;
    int calories;
};
int main()
{
    char a[20] = "Mocha Munch";
    cout << a;
    CandyBar snack;
    snack.brand = "Mocha Munch";
    snack.weight = 2.3;
    snack.calories = 350;
    cout << "Brand of snack: " << snack.brand << endl;
    cout << "Weight of snack: " << snack.weight << endl;
    cout << "Calories of snack: " << snack.calories << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is why with `a[20]` I can assign it to the array, but with `brand` I cannot.

Comment: _"why with `a[20]` I can assign it to the array"_ You can't.

Answer (score 5):

```
char a[20] = "Mocha Munch";
```

This is *initialisation* of character array `a` (*not* assignment). The language specifically allows initialising character arrays from string literals.

```
snack.brand = "Mocha Munch";
```

This is *assignment* into an array. The language does not allow assigning entire arrays (at all).

If you want to use a string in C++, don't waste time with cumbersome, error-prone character arrays. Use `std::string`.